# Bluetooth Radio.StateChanged Event fires twice

Tags: c#, windows

I want to listen when bluetooth radio turn on or turn off.
For this i simply got the default radio and subscribed to StateChanged.

```
var bluetoothAdapter = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();
var radio = await bluetoothAdapter.GetRadioAsync();
radio.StateChanged += Radio_StateChanged;

private void Radio_StateChanged(Windows.Devices.Radios.Radio sender, object args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Radio state changed {0} {1}", sender.Kind, sender.Name));
}
```

When i change bluetooth state via Windows Bluetooth settings i got StateChanged event fires twice.

Output:

```
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth
```

I have the module with Bluetooth and Wifi together. I thought maybe it is cause. Then i get all radios `Radio.GetRadiosAsync`

```
radios = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();
foreach (var r in radios)
{
    r.StateChanged += Radio_StateChanged;
}
```

Output:

```
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth
Radio state changed WiFi Wi-Fi
Radio state changed WiFi Wi-Fi
```

is this the expected behavior?

Update. I added state value to output

Output:

```
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth Off
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth Off
```

Comment: Can you check if the code adding the event isn't called twice?
Can you also check the content of the event? Maybe there is a "starting" state and a "started" state, causing your event to be called twice.

Comment: If you have more than one Radio Button using the same event you w2ill get two events since one button will be checked and the other button will be unchecked.

Comment: @Arcord I added to output "state" value. There are only on or off state.
"
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth Off
Radio state changed Bluetooth Bluetooth Off
"
and i use the same code as i wrote. I call the StateChanged only once

Comment: @jdweng This is Bluetooth Radio not a button radio

Comment: Do you have more than one device?  Look at radio variable properties.

Comment: @jdweng no. I have only 1 wi-fi device and 1 bt device.

Comment: The code will find  change for each radio.  If a bt is a radio that would explain the two changes.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean? I have only one bluetooth and I get only 1 radio var radio = await bluetoothAdapter.GetRadioAsync();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug of **Radio.StateChanged** API. I have also faced the same problem. You can minimize the problem by checking the Radio State like bellow :

```
public Radio BluetoothAdapter { get; set; }
public RadioState OldBluetoothState;
public RadioState NewBluetoothState;


IReadOnlyList<Radio> radios = await Radio.GetRadiosAsync();
BluetoothAdapter = radios.FirstOrDefault(radio => radio.Kind == RadioKind.Bluetooth);
if (BluetoothAdapter != null)
{
   OldBluetoothState = BluetoothAdapter.State;
   BluetoothAdapter.StateChanged += RadioBluetoothAdapter_StateChanged;
}

private void RadioBluetoothAdapter_StateChanged(Radio sender, object args)
{
  try
  {
    NewBluetoothState = sender.State;
    if (NewBluetoothState != OldBluetoothState)
    {
        OldBluetoothState = NewBluetoothState;

        if (sender.State == RadioState.Off)
        {
            //Application logic will goes here.
            Debug.WriteLine("Bluetooth has been turned off.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Application logic will goes here.
            Debug.WriteLine("Bluetooth has been turned on.");
        }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     Debug.WriteLine($"Exception has been occured: {ex.Message.ToString()}");
  }
}
```